# How to generate SDP file from FFMPEG

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, video-streaming, rtp, sdp

So, I have been working with FFMPEG on a project that involves streaming video from one computer to another across the internet with RTP. I want to take that into ffmpeg and use ffserver to display it on a local network.

As I understand it, you need to have a SDP information so that the receiving ffmpeg instance can interpret the RTP stream. Despite what webpages say, I can not find the SDP information in the information printed to the console.

How can I force the transmitting ffmpeg instance to output the SDP information so that I can use it to configure my receiving end?

Right now, I am testing on Windows 7, but the final solution will be on linux.

The command I'm running for testing is

```
ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -i files\2005-SFSD-sample-mpeg1.mpg -threads 0 -r 10 -g 45
-s 352x240 -deinterlace -y 2005.mp4 -an -threads 0 -r 10 -g 45 -s 352x240 
-deinterlace -f rtp rtp://192.168.200.198:9008
```

My ffmpeg information is...

```
ffmpeg version 0.8, Copyright (c) 2000-2011 the FFmpeg developers built on Jun 23 2011 14:22:23 with gcc 4.5.3 
configuration: 
--disable-static  
--enable-shared 
--enable-gpl  
--enable-version3 
--enable-memalign-hack  
--enable-runtime-cpudetect 
--enable-avisynth 
--enable-bzlib 
--enable-frei0r 
--enable-libopencore-amrnb 
--enable-libopencore-amrwb 
--enable-libfreetype 
--enable-libgsm 
--enable-libmp3lame 
--enable-libopenjpeg 
--enable-librtmp 
--enable-libschroedinger 
--enable-libspeex 
--enable-libtheora 
--enable-libvorbis 
--enable-libvpx 
--enable-libx264 
--enable-libxavs 
--enable-libxvid 
--enable-zlib 
--disable-outdev=sdl 
  libavutil    51.  9. 1 / 51.  9. 1 
  libavcodec   53.  7. 0 / 53.  7. 0 
  libavformat  53.  4. 0 / 53.  4. 0 
  libavdevice  53.  1. 1 / 53.  1. 1 
  libavfilter   2. 23. 0 /  2. 23. 0 
  libswscale    2.  0. 0 /  2.  0. 0 
  libpostproc  51.  2. 0 / 51.  2. 0
```

Answer (score 5):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16469378/2097284 explains in more detail how to make the `.sdp` file, and how to pass that to `ffplay`.

Answer (score 4):

Just in case anyone was looking to find how to do this with ffmpeg C code, you can use `av_sdp_create` to [generate an sdp string](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.8/group__lavf__misc.html#gaa2a7353a6bb0c8726797abd56b176af0)

Answer (score 4):

FFMPG generates a SDP file when specified with [`-sdp_file path/to/file`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html)

Documentation excerpt:

`-sdp_file file (global)
    Print sdp information for an output stream to file. This allows 
    dumping sdp information when at least one output isn’t an rtp stream. 
    (Requires at least one of the output formats to be rtp).`

Comment: I love you o/ You saved me from a lot of headaches

Comment: What is its full command ?

Answer (score 2):

Normally when the output is one rtp stream, ffmpeg prints the sdp information in the console so you just have to redirect it (and then use the sdp ):

```
ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -i files\2005-SFSD-sample-mpeg1.mpg  -an -threads 0 -r 10 -g 45 -s 352x240 -deinterlace -f rtp rtp://192.168.200.198:9008 > config.sdp
```

But from your command it looks like you want to do one encoding for two outputs ... 
if the two outputs are rtp (helpful for video + audio) it works fine , but I couldnt
get it to print the sdp when 1 output is rtp and the other mp4  ... not sure if possible

Anyway what you can do though is to generate the sdp file for the first time, and as long as you dont change the video characteristics (resolution format ...) or the rtp address this sdp file will be valid, and your previous command would work with it !!

hope this helps

Comment: http://lucabe72.blogspot.com/2010/04/rtp-streaming-with-ffmpeg.html may be related

Comment: This is my command: ffmpeg -i rtp://239.255.42.42:5004 c:/33030ooo.mp4 > c:/config.sdp      -----    but made config.sdp is empty!

Comment: @Mr.Hyde you want to stream the mp4 video through rtp , right ?
Try this (i have not tested it with new ffmpeg cli)
`ffmpeg -i c:/33030ooo.mp4 rtp://239.255.42.42:5004 > c:/config.sdp`