# Why rtp streaming of a .avi video file fails to be received?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, rtp

In [ffmpeg streamingGuide](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/StreamingGuide), it writes:

```
ffmpeg -re -f lavfi -i aevalsrc="sin(400*2*PI*t)" -ar 8000 -f mulaw -f rtp rtp://127.0.0.1:1234 &
ffplay rtp://127.0.0.1:1234
```

I want to use a real video file to replace the artificial signal.
Then I write the below at terminal A:

```
ffmpeg -re -i outputFile.avi -f mulaw -f rtp rtp://127.0.0.1:1234
```

it seems it is working:
The frame information is counting. Here are information on the terminal A at the end:

```
frame=  309 fps= 29 q=31.0 Lsize=     931kB time=00:00:10.30 bitrate= 740.8kbits/s     video:922kB audio:0kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 1.030813%
```

When the frame at terminal A is still counting (not finished), I type the below at terminal B:

```
ffplay rtp://127.0.0.1:1234
```

But it does not work:
The error information is:

```
[udp @ 0x7fb370001500] bind failed: Address already in useB f=0/0   
rtp://127.0.0.1:1234: Input/output error
```

Why?

[Update 1] Following the instruction from Camille Goudeseune
I used the foo.sdp
The input for the ffmpeg terminal is:

> ffmpeg -re -i out.avi -f mulaw -f rtp rtp://127.0.0.1:1235

The terminal for ffplay is:

> ffplay -i foo.sdp

The ffplay terminal shows a lot of error, without images.

```
  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
[sdp @ 0x7fafdc0008c0] Undefined type (30)    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[sdp @ 0x7fafdc0008c0] nal size exceeds length: 25453 86 0B f=0/0   
[sdp @ 0x7fafdc0008c0] Consumed more bytes than we got! (-25367)
[sdp @ 0x7fafdc0008c0] nal size exceeds length: 25453 86
[sdp @ 0x7fafdc0008c0] Consumed more bytes than we got! (-25367)
[sdp @ 0x7fafdc0008c0] Unhandled type (27) (See RFC for implementation details
[sdp @ 0x7fafdc0008c0] Undefined type (31)    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[sdp @ 0x7fafdc0008c0] Unhandled type (27) (See RFC for implementation details
[sdp @ 0x7fafdc0008c0] nal size exceeds length: 62414 6130B f=0/0   
[sdp @ 0x7fafdc0008c0] Consumed more bytes than we got! (-61801)
[sdp @ 0x7fafdc0008c0] nal size exceeds length: 62414 613
[sdp @ 0x7fafdc0008c0] Consumed more bytes than we got! (-61801)
[h264 @ 0x7fafdc003020] non-existing PPS referencedq=    0B f=0/0   
[h264 @ 0x7fafdc003020] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7fafdc003020] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7fafdc003020] Invalid mix of idr and non-idr slices
[sdp @ 0x7fafdc0008c0] Undefined type (31)    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[sdp @ 0x7fafdc0008c0] Unhandled type (29) (See RFC for implementation details
[sdp @ 0x7fafdc0008c0] Unhandled type (26) (See RFC for implementation details
[sdp @ 0x7fafdc0008c0] Unhandled type (27) (See RFC for implementation details
    Last message repeated 2 times  0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[sdp @ 0x7fafdc0008c0] Undefined type (31)
[sdp @ 0x7fafdc0008c0] Unhandled type (26) (See RFC for implementation details
[sdp @ 0x7fafdc0008c0] Unhandled type (25) (See RFC for implementation details
[h264 @ 0x7fafdc003020] insane cropping not completely supported, this could look slightly wrong ... (left: 2, top: 2)
[h264 @ 0x7fafdc003020] illegal aspect ratio
[h264 @ 0x7fafdc003020] missing picture in access unit with size 84589
[h264 @ 0x7fafdc003020] Partitioned H.264 support is incomplete
[h264 @ 0x7fafdc003020] insane cropping not completely supported, this could look slightly wrong ... (left: 2, top: 2)
[h264 @ 0x7fafdc003020] illegal aspect ratio
[h264 @ 0x7fafdc003020] insane cropping not completely supported, this could look slightly wrong ... (left: 2, top: 2)
[h264 @ 0x7fafdc003020] illegal aspect ratio
[h264 @ 0x7fafdc003020] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7fafdc003020] RTP: missed 2563 packetsB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[sdp @ 0x7fafdc0008c0] Undefined type (30)
    Last message repeated 1 times
[sdp @ 0x7fafdc0008c0] Undefined type (31)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Instead of `ffplay rtp://127.0.0.1:1235`, use `ffplay -i foo.sdp`.

Create the local file `foo.sdp` by pasting into it the text output from ffmpeg that follows the line `SDP:`, for example:

```
v=0
o=- 0 0 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=No Name
c=IN IP4 127.0.0.1
t=0 0
a=tool:libavformat 55.2.100
m=video 1235 RTP/AVP 96
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1
```

The .sdp file includes the rtp address, so you need not specify rtp://... as well.

Comment: I used the foo.sdp  The input for the ffmpeg terminal is: ffmpeg -re -i out.avi -f mulaw -f rtp rtp://127.0.0.1:1235          The terminal for ffplay is: ffplay -i foo.sdp        The ffplay terminal shows a lot of error, without images.

Comment: [sdp @ 00000000003759c0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h2
64, none): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
C:\rtp.sdp: could not find codec parameters
    nan    :  0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0

Comment: I got some `Protocol not on whitelist 'file'!`, so I just added `-protocol_whitelist file,udp,rtp`.

Answer (score 4):

`ffplay rtp://127.0.0.1:1234` will start listening on UDP-port `1234` for incoming RTP-traffic.

only a single application can listen on any given port on a host at any given time.

the error "bind failed: Address already in use" indicates, that another application is already listening on port `1234`.
probably you are still running the script from your tests?

either stop the application that is blocking the port, or use a different port.

Comment: Hmm, if `SO_REUSEADDR` and or `SO_REUSEPORT` are set to true it is entirely possible to bind two different processes to same IP address and TCP port.

Comment: yes, but it will most likely not do what you would like to do. when using `SO_REUSEPORT` a package received will *NOT* turn up at *all* listeners, but only at one (which one is decided by the operating system, e.g. using a round-robin algorithm). this is cool for building a load-balancer, but for few other things (i cannot think of any)